# Intellij not able to access jdk

Tags: software-installation, java, openjdk, jdk, intellij

I am using Linux mint 20 (Posting it here as mint is based on Ubuntu). It has OpenJdk 11 (Checked it using --version), but Intellij doesn't recognise it. So, I tried adding it manually. I found that java is stored at 'usr/lib/jvm/open-jdk-11/bin/'. When I try to open it from the file chooser that Intellij opens, I can't reach java, it shows that 'bin' is empty (It is not, I can see it when I open it using nemo).

I first installed Intellij using snap, but soon found out the problem I am facing is with the permissions, because of the sandbox feature. So, I removed it. Then, installed it again with the .tar.gz provided on the main site. I extracted it in /opt (as recommended on the site). But, it the tar.gz doesn't fix the problem. So, I tried removing the cashe and other configs after following the documenation from jetbrains. It still didn't fix it.

The wierd thing is that when I first installed it, it didn't give me any configuration settings (Changing theme, etc...) like seen on the site. Is it because it is a newer version? I am using Intellij community 2021.1

Sorry that I have written an essay  , I just wanted to give all the info I can give

:)

Comment: Mint is based on Ubuntu but it isn't an official derivative therefore is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a problem installing Intelij I wanted to suggest trying their toolbox app for managing IDEs and their versions. It's really easy to setup.

1. [Go to the official site](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/)
2. Download `.tar.gz`
3. Extract it anywhere
4. Run the binary
5. Choose the Intelij version that you want and install it

Comment: The OP already did it - *installed it again with the .tar.gz provided on the main site* - plus this question is off-topic (Mint) and likely to be closed soon.

Comment: Thanks @tsopeh, It worked. I downloaded an older version and it recognised it